# How to prioritize selected data based on specific column in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have 2 tables below:

table1

| store_name | store_code | sub_channel |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 12345 | C021 |
| B | 56789 | C021 |
| C | 10000 | C021 |

table2

| product_code | store_code | sub_channel | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X1 | 12345 |  | 10 |
| X1 |  | C021 | 20 |
| X2 | 12345 | C021 | 50 |
| X3 | 56789 | C021 | 20 |
| X4 |  | C021 | 40 |
| X5 | 56789 |  | 100 |

I want to fetch the data from table2 based on store_code or sub_channel but only showing data only if there is the data based on store_code then select only from store_code and if it's not then select from sub_channel.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT t1.store_name, t2.*
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.store_code = t1.store_code OR t2.sub_channel = t1.sub_channel
ORDER BY t1.store_name, t2.product_code
```

I got result as below:

| store_name | product_code | store_code | sub_channel | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | X1 | 12345 |  | 10 |
| A | X1 |  | C021 | 20 |
| A | X2 | 12345 | C021 | 50 |
| A | X3 | 56789 | C021 | 20 |
| A | X4 |  | C021 | 40 |
| B | X1 |  | C021 | 20 |
| B | X2 | 12345 | C021 | 50 |
| B | X3 | 56789 | C021 | 20 |
| B | X4 |  | C021 | 40 |
| B | X5 | 56789 |  | 100 |
| C | X1 |  | C021 | 20 |
| C | X2 | 12345 | C021 | 50 |
| C | X3 | 56789 | C021 | 20 |
| C | X4 |  | C021 | 40 |

What I want to achieve here as below:

| store_name | product_code | store_code | sub_channel | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | X1 | 12345 |  | 10 |
| A | X2 | 12345 | C021 | 50 |
| B | X3 | 56789 | C021 | 20 |
| B | X5 | 56789 |  | 100 |
| C | X1 |  | C021 | 20 |
| C | X2 | 12345 | C021 | 50 |
| C | X3 | 56789 | C021 | 20 |
| C | X4 |  | C021 | 40 |

Is there any way to achieve this and which additional code to add up in my query to achieve this?

Comment: I have some uncertainty as to how you obtained the desired result from the provided example table 1 and table 2....

Looking at the list: 

You classify A1 as store A but dont sum the A1 products (30 total?)
you classify A2 as store A based on store_code
you classify A3 as C (but its store_code is B!?)
you classify A4 as C (sub_code but why isnt this counted towards A or B then?)
you classify A5 as store B (Storecode)


From the looks of it you should try conditionally joining a Store to an item rather then inverse or use sumations

Comment: Basically product code doesn't have any connection with the store name they are different entity. They are connected by store code or sub channel and data with the same product code but have different store code and sub channel value are different entity so the qty of each product code it belongs to each entity. I already edited the example to make it clear. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: B should also have X3 in the output in my view - can you explain why it doesn't

Comment: My bad, actually B should also have X3. Thank you for the notice. Edited already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can do this with two `LEFT JOIN`s:

```
select t1.*, 
    coalesce(t21.product_code, t22.product_code) product_code,
    coalesce(t21.qty, t22.qty) qty
from table1 t1
left join table2 t21 on t21.store_code = t1.store_code
left join table2 t22 on t22.sub_channel = t1.sub_channel and t21.store_code is null
order by store_name, product_code
```

The first join attempts to match on the store code; the second join targets the sub-channel - with an additional condition that ensures that only rows that did no match on the first join are taken into account.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UG3Rko5s)**:

| store_name | store_code | sub_channel | product_code | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 12345 | C021 | X1 | 10 |
| A | 12345 | C021 | X2 | 50 |
| B | 56789 | C021 | X3 | 20 |
| B | 56789 | C021 | X5 | 100 |
| C | 10000 | C021 | X1 | 20 |
| C | 10000 | C021 | X2 | 50 |
| C | 10000 | C021 | X3 | 20 |
| C | 10000 | C021 | X4 | 40 |

Answer (score 0):

Why not UNION ?

```
SELECT ax.* FROM (
select * from table1 t1 where ifnull(store_code,'') <> ''
UNION 
select * from table1 t1 where ifnull(store_channel,'') <> '') ax 
order by ax.store_name, ax.product_code ;
```